# Remote connection to my server is very slow

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, remote-access, download-speed

I entered the world of self-hosting last week: I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 on an old PC, installed Nextcloud on it and tried to use it as a “Google Drive alternative”.

I configured it properly so that I can access it remotely (opened router ports, port forwarding,...) and everything works but the connection from outside the local network is very slow (1.5 MB/s both for Upload and Download).

Initially I thought it could have been because my PC was quite old, but then I did some tests directly on the server (moving files, copying files from a USB drive,...) and the speed was way better then the 1.5MB/s I got remotely.

So I thought that the problem could be in the network the server is connected to but, even though I don’t have a super fast internet (35Mb/s download, 20Mb/s upload), I think that connection could be at least a bit faster than my current 1.5MB/s.

I thought it could be a problem with my Nextcloud installation but the connection behaves the same for other apps (fast while server and client are in the same network, very slow while accessing it from a different network)

So I really don’t know where the problem is and how to solve it... Did anyone have the same problem and can help me solving it?

EDIT: Result of the command `ip link` (asked in the comments):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:6c:de:cc:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: What's your connection? WiFi or wired? What's your MTU? `ip link` to see MTU. S/B 1492  for wireless.

Comment: Wired connection... I'll add the result of _ip link_ in the question

Comment: You say you have 20Mb/s upload. That is 2.5 MB/s. So the speed you get is not that far from it. For a fileserver, 20Mb/s uplink is slow.

Comment: Uh...  so it’s something I can’t fix :(
and what should be the minimum upload and download speed?